# Could not connect secured LDAP server from other PC (CentOS)

Tags: java, ldap, spring-security-ldap

I have created an LDAP server on my pc which has both secured and non-secured connections created. I have configured my Spring-MVC application to connect to LDAP servers in both secured and non-secured ways.

When I try to connect the LDAP server from MY pc it is working fine. But when I try to connect from other pc in the office network, using secured connection is not working. There is a connection error happening (Most probably, `javax.naming.NamingException`). But the non-secured connection is OK.

**Below is the secured connection details.**

[image]

**Connection parameters**

[image]

Are there any settings/permissions required for connecting the LDAP server from the remote machine? However, I have added the firewall settings on the remote machine (CentOS) using following command:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=ldap --permanent
```

Please let me know if more details are required.

Comment: On the server check the `slapd` configuration file (`/etc/sysconfig/slapd`), ensure you have LDAPS enabled : `SLAPD_LDAPS=yes`, you should also have `ldaps://` set as one of the supported URLS : `SLAPD_URLS="ldapi:/// ldap:/// ldaps:///"`. Then, since LDAP over SSL/TLS needs the system firewall to allow incoming TCP connections on port 636 instead of 389, you might have to run `firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=636/tcp`.

Comment: Thanks, @EricLavault, maybe port number 636 not added could be the issue. Anyways, I will try to use your suggestions. Will let you know if they work. :)